# How do you set SchemaType options on arrays of a specified type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I understand how to add validation to say, a `Number`:

```
new Schema({
  name: { type: Number, min: 10 }
});
```

But how would you do this for an `Array`? You could do this:

```
new Schema({
  stuff: { type: Array, required: true }
});
```

But what if you want to specify that it's an array of `Numbers`?

```
new Schema({
  stuff: [Number]
});
```

How would you add `min: 10`?

Answer (score 0):

If your array is of a [SchemaType](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.Types) like `Number`, you would do this:

```
new Schema({
  stuff: [{ type: Number, min: 10 }]
});
```

If your array is of [Sub-Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

```
new Schema({
  stuff: { type: [subDocumentSchema], select: false }
});
```

Comment: http://jasonjl.me/blog/2014/10/23/adding-validation-for-embedded-objects-in-mongoose/ is a good read. Although `//will make it so that the feature's array will be required to save this document` didn't prove true for me. Maybe Mongoose has changed since the time that article was written?